# How do I query for records which got created within a short window

Tags: mysql, database-design

```
create table users (id, created_date, ...)


insert into users (1, '2014-01-01 05.00.00')
insert into users (2, '2014-01-01 05.00.01')
insert into users (3, '2014-01-01 05.00.10')
insert into users (4, '2014-01-01 05.00.11')
insert into users (5, '2014-01-01 05.00.20')
insert into users (6, '2014-01-01 05.00.30')
insert into users (7, '2014-01-02 05.00.01')
insert into users (8, '2014-01-02 05.00.02')
insert into users (9, '2014-01-02 05.00.03')
insert into users (10, '2014-01-02 05.00.03')
insert into users (11, '2014-01-02 06.00.03')
insert into users (12, '2014-01-02 07.00.03')
```

How do I query for users who got created within a small window (say a sec, across the entire table). In the above scenario, we can group this as follows

```
[1,2], [3,4], [7,8,9]
```

Comment: Appreciate if you can provide some pointers to resolve this issue.

Comment: If you're going to provide DDLs, consider doing so properly.

Comment: Should the last group of your expected results include 10 since it was created the same time as 9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use this query with variables:

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(id)
FROM (
  SELECT
    id,
    created_date,
    @grp:= CASE WHEN created_date>@last_dt + INTERVAL 1 SECOND
                THEN @grp+1
                ELSE @grp END grp,
    @last_dt := created_date
  FROM
    users, (SELECT @grp := 1, @last_dt := NULL) r
  ORDER BY
    created_date
  ) s
GROUP BY
  grp
HAVING
  COUNT(*)>1
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/341e2/1). It will return:

```
[1,2], [3,4], [7,8,9,10]
```

and I think it's correct and it's what you are looking for. Subquery will order table by crerated_date, and will assign every row in a group, incrementing it's number everytime the increment between the previous value is more than one second:

```
| ID |                   CREATED_DATE | GRP | @LAST_DT := CREATED_DATE |
|----|--------------------------------|-----|--------------------------|
|  1 | January, 01 2014 05:00:00+0000 |   1 |      2014-01-01 05:00:00 |
|  2 | January, 01 2014 05:00:01+0000 |   1 |      2014-01-01 05:00:01 |
|  3 | January, 01 2014 05:00:10+0000 |   2 |      2014-01-01 05:00:10 |
|  4 | January, 01 2014 05:00:11+0000 |   2 |      2014-01-01 05:00:11 |
|  5 | January, 01 2014 05:00:20+0000 |   3 |      2014-01-01 05:00:20 |
...
```

I'm then grouping this result by GRP, using GROUP_CONCAT and returning all Groups that have more than one row.

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider doing a self-join like this:

```
SELECT
    u1.id id1,
    u1.created_date created_date1,
    u2.id id2,
    u2.created_date created_date2
FROM
    users u1
    JOIN users u2
        ON u1.id < u2.id
        AND u1.created_date
            BETWEEN u2.created_date - INTERVAL 1 SECOND
            AND u2.created_date
```

[[SQL Fiddle]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b49bf/9)

It will not give you the result exactly in the format you asked for. Instead, it will give you what is essentially a set of **graph edges**, from which you can then find the [connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29) in client code.

For example, running the above query on your test data gives...

```
ID1 CREATED_DATE1                   ID2 CREATED_DATE2
1   January, 01 2014 05:00:00+0000  2   January, 01 2014 05:00:01+0000
3   January, 01 2014 05:00:10+0000  4   January, 01 2014 05:00:11+0000
7   January, 02 2014 05:00:01+0000  8   January, 02 2014 05:00:02+0000
8   January, 02 2014 05:00:02+0000  9   January, 02 2014 05:00:03+0000
8   January, 02 2014 05:00:02+0000  10  January, 02 2014 05:00:03+0000
9   January, 02 2014 05:00:03+0000  10  January, 02 2014 05:00:03+0000
```

...which contains 3 connected components:

```
{
    1   January, 01 2014 05:00:00+0000
    2   January, 01 2014 05:00:01+0000
}
{
    3   January, 01 2014 05:00:10+0000
    4   January, 01 2014 05:00:11+0000
}
{
    7   January, 02 2014 05:00:01+0000
    8   January, 02 2014 05:00:02+0000
    9   January, 02 2014 05:00:03+0000
    10  January, 02 2014 05:00:03+0000
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example suggests that you are trying to perform some sort of [cluster analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) with "less that one second from the previous record" as the determining function.  I'd suggest you invert the question and look for gaps of more than one second in your data.  This has been [well covered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22sql%22+find+gaps+in+sequence) on SO.  The lower and upper limits of the gaps will be the upper and lower limits, respectively, of the neighbouring clusters.  Clusters with one member and the first and last cluster will be special cases you'll have to decide what to do with.